# Как в java передавать значение коллекции в другой объект?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

Например у нас есть entity,  в которой содержится ArrayList, получаю эту сущность и как правильно смапить в Dto?
Какие есть способы и лучшие практики?
Использовать неизменяемые коллекции, clone или как?

Comment: mapstruct? Правильных и лучших практик нет. Сильно зависит от архитектуры и закладываемой логики. В это время года популярны records

Comment: Рекомендуется передавать как минимум _копию_ коллекции, дополнительно эта копия может быть неизменяемой.  Также вашем случае, скорее всего, потребуется конвертация элементов коллекции в соответствующий  Dto (при помощи mapstruct, билдеров и т.п.)

Comment: Спасибо, с утра заклинило) на автомате на котлине так и делаю,  через стрим удобно, он всегда же возвращает новую коллекцию и плюс внутри сразу к объекту dto маппинг.